# ls-a command not found

Tags: linux

I am currently taking a Computing GCSE and need a bit of help with Linux. I am very new to Linux, and this is the Controlled Assessment:

*At the command prompt, type ls -a. Demonstrate and explain what happens. Modify this
command so that it only shows hidden files beginning with the letter ‘b’*.

Here is what I get output when I type `ls-a`

```
ls-a: command not found
```

I don't know whether this is supposed to happen or not, but if it isn't can you please help to make it work properly?

Thanks! ;)

Edit:
I now have the answer, turns out I forgot a space! Thank You klepzers!

Comment: You need a space between the ls and the -a.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should type `ls -a` instead of `ls-a`.
Because `-a` is an argument.

Answer (score 3):

You need a space between "ls" and "-a"

ls -a

ls is command and "-a" is parameter!

Comment: Not an "attribute", an argument or parameter.